# HTML Forms - Back and Next Buttons

Tags: forms

I am building a multi-page form for my website. Each page has several fields and a Back Button and Next Button. The Next Button takes the user to the next page of the form. I have achieved this by adding a input button like `<input type="submit" value="Next Step">`. The Form action is set to a different php page. A Back button lets user go back to the previous page and make changes if any. For this, I added `<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);">`

I have also added `header('Cache-Control: max-age=900');` to all my pages. I also use Sessions to store data.

On clicking the back button, I can see all my previously entered text in the first form. But, on clicking the Next button, text entered in the next form disappears.

My question is, how can the user entered data be stored inspite of clicking the Next button. The browser forward button keeps the data though!

Answer (score 0):

I may prefer you to use more elegant way of storing your forms' data by using any kind of local storage api. There is already an api that will do that for you:

[Garlic.js](http://garlicjs.org/)

I'm not the developer of this api and I haven't tasted it by myself, but I've seen other people suggesting it to people.